# multiple conditional renderings inside a map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi there I'm looking if there's a better way to render my todos

I have this

```
         {
            todos.map((todo) => (
                
                todo.status === 1 && (
                    <p>{todo.title}</p>
                )
            ))
        }
        {
            todos.map((todo) => (
                todo.status === 2 && (
                    <p>{todo.title}</p>
                )
            ))
        }
        {
            todos.map((todo) => (
                todo.status === 3 && (
                    <p>{todo.title}</p>
                )
            ))
        }
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: `todo.status === 1 || todo.status === 2 || todo.status === 3`

Comment: I know this, but I wanted to list items based on status that's why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want them to be in order, then sort them before you map them

```
todos.sort((a, b) => a.status - b.status).map((todo) => .....)
```

if you do not want to change the order of the original array then copy it

```
todos.slice().sort((a, b) => a.status - b.status).map((todo) => .....)
```

Comment: `[...todos].sort()` will also replicate the array

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera - Yes, there are lots of ways to copy arrays. Or for the copy-and-sort operation, [a Stage 2 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-change-array-by-copy) will give us `todos.toSorted((a, b) => a.status - b.status).map(/*...*/)`.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, copy-and-sort operation in a single function called `toSorted`. That's nice !!

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming they really are all right next to each other like that. If so:, either:

1. Sort `todos` before rendering
2. Use an outer loop of status values

#### Sort

Sort the `todos` array, ideally just the once prior to rendering/re-rendering.

```
todos.sort((a, b) => a.status - b.status);
```

Note that this assumes there are only those three `status` values. If there are others, you may want to have a separate filtered and sorted array that you rebuild when `todos` changes.

#### Outer loop

```
{[1, 2, 3].map(
    status => todos.map(
        todo => todo.status === status && <p>{todo.title}</p>
    )
)}
```

---

Side note: Those `p` elements need [keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and all others I understood it very well thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility (assuming you want to e.g. put `<h2>` headings between the different types of todos) would be to use `filter`:

```
// get all todos with status 1
todos.filter(todo => todo.status === 1).map(todo => (<p key={todo.id}>{todo.title}</p>))
```

<del>If you want to show them as a continuous array, the sort approach is better.</del>

EDIT:
Since @epascarello insisted that more loops were bad, I wrote a quick little benchmark (takes a while before the console output starts showing up, simplified not to use React)

```js
const REPEAT_TESTS = 1000;


function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

for (let elements of [1, 10, 100, 1000, 100000]) {
  console.warn(`trying all three approaches with ${elements} todo items`);
  const array = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
    array.push({
      title: "item " + i,
      status: getRandomInt(3) + 1
    })
  }

  // map only
  let start = performance.now();
  for (let i = 0; i < REPEAT_TESTS; i++) {
    const result1 = array.map(elem => (elem.status === 1 && elem.title));
    const result2 = array.map(elem => (elem.status === 2 && elem.title));
    const result3 = array.map(elem => (elem.status === 3 && elem.title));
  }
  let elapsed = performance.now() - start;
  console.log(`map only took ${elapsed} ms (${elapsed/REPEAT_TESTS}ms per iteration)`);

  // .filter.map()
  start = performance.now();
  for (let i = 0; i < REPEAT_TESTS; i++) {
    const result1 = array.filter(elem => elem.status === 1).map(elem => elem.title);
    const result2 = array.filter(elem => elem.status === 2).map(elem => elem.title);
    const result3 = array.filter(elem => elem.status === 3).map(elem => elem.title);
  }
  elapsed = performance.now() - start;
  console.log(`.filter().map() took ${elapsed} ms (${elapsed/REPEAT_TESTS}ms per iteration)`);

  // test 3
  start = performance.now();
  for (let i = 0; i < REPEAT_TESTS; i++) {
    const sorted = array.slice().sort((a, b) => a.status - b.status).map(elem => elem.title);
  }
  elapsed = performance.now() - start;
  console.log(`Test 3 took ${elapsed} ms (${elapsed/REPEAT_TESTS}ms per iteration)`);
}
```

This clearly shows that for `todos.length >= 100`

- OPs solution is fastest (because yes, the filter adds some loops. But OPS solution also returns `false` for all the non matching elements which is completely unusable in data processing and might incur some performance penalty in React's handling of the values)
- `.filter.map` is slightly slower but more readable and does not have the problem of returning `false` values
- `sort` is slow for more than a couple of elements and gets slower quickly. I tried this example in Nodejs with 10.000.000 elements and these were the results:

```
map only took 42667.75609499961 ms (42.66775609499961ms per iteration)
.filter.map took 56544.36275900155 ms (56.54436275900155ms per iteration)
sort took 107536.24900600314 ms (107.53624900600315ms per iteration)
```

In conclusion I would always go with `.filter.map` chained. The benchmark also assumes the cheapest possible `map` function (just returning the name), for a more expensive `map` function the difference will be even smaller.

Comment: Your solution with filter would cause 6 loops instead of the 3 the user had.

Comment: While that is true, the time complexity is not higher (O(2n) ~ O(n)), and the `map` function is invoked only on the filtered, shorter arrays. So `map` will be called only `todos.length` times in total.

Comment: Yes, but you are doing more iterations than before. Filter really is not buying you anything. Also does not really help OP limiting the code down.

Comment: It follows a pattern that is very commonly used in JS, does not return `null` values in the array as in OPs example (which does not matter for rendering but would for data processing) and only slows down proportionally to the length of items. The sort approach should actually be slower than this for huge arrays, because it's O(n * log(n))

Answer (score 0):

You can filter those todos first then render later

```
todos.filter(todo => todo.status === 1).map(todo => (
    <p>{todo.title}</p>
))

todos.filter(todo => todo.status === 2).map(todo => (
    <p>{todo.title}</p>
))

todos.filter(todo => todo.status === 3).map(todo => (
    <p>{todo.title}</p>
))
```

or create a reuseable function to render those todos

```
function renderTodoWithStatus(todos, status) {
    return todos.filter(todo => todo.status === status).map(todo => (
        <p>{todo.title}</p>
    ))
}
```

Comment: Now it looks 6 times instead of 3.

Answer (score 0):

Making no assumptions about the status, you could do something like this:

```js
const getTodos = (status) => todos
  .filter((todo) => todo.status === status)
  .map((todo) => <p>{todo.title}</p>);
...
{getTodos(1)}
{getTodos(2)}
{getTodos(3)}
```

Comment: Now it looks 6 times instead of 3.